# eliminar imagen previa en multiple upload javascript junto a la de propiedad del elemento del input

Tags: javascript, fileupload, upload

Tengo el siguiente script con el cuál hago multiple upload de imagenes con vista previa.
También tiene opción de eliminar una o más de las vistas por el botón eliminar que aparece al lado de cada imagen.

El tema es que se elimina la vista previa de la seleccionada/s, pero al realizar el upload, van todas la imagenes seleccionadas inicialmente indiferentes si las había eliminado de la vista previa o no.

Es decir me elimina las previas pero envía toda la seleccion inicial del input.

Si alguien me puede dar una mano, desde ya agradecido...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.3.0/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<form action="test_upload1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="col-md-12 my-5 mx-4">
<input type="file" id="uploadImageFile"  accept="image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/gif" class="form-control" name="uploadImageFile[]" onchange="showImageHereFunc();" multiple/>
<div id="showImageHere"></div>
</div>
<button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showImageHereFunc() {
  var total_file=document.getElementById("uploadImageFile").files.length;
  for(var i=0;i<total_file;i++) {
    $('#showImageHere').append("<div class='cardo'><img src='"+URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i])+"'><button onclick='borrar(this)'>Eliminar</button></div>");
  }
}

function borrar(div) { 
  div.parentNode.remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero que el `console.log` lo pongas al inicio para que sepas que estas recibiendo; pues es a eso que **obtiene su padre (contenedor) y lo eliminas**, no haces referencia al archivo. A simple vista al elemento `this` (lo que sea) estas obteniendo su padre (donde despliegas las vistas previas) y eliminas este contenedor.

Comment: Gracias Roberto, lo corregí como esta funcionando ahora. La verdad no tengo mucho conocimiento de JS, asi que todo es a prueba y error. Pero no se por donde entrarle ahora para solucionar el tema. Que además del contendor de vista previa, me elimine el archivo seleccionado en el input.

Comment: Saludos de nuevo.  Todos empezamos aprendiendo y en la ruta aprendiendo. Date "una vuelta" por las propiedades de elemento file (como tal el objeto que representa y tiene su nombre); yo tuve situación similar y "lo ataque" creando un array donde cada vez que seleccionaban un archivo lo mandaba al array; y ya en este podia borrarlo (es decir el input no lo usaba mas que para seleccionar el archivo). Para enviar los archivos lo que hacia es procesar los del array (los que no se eliminaban de la lista).